# Embed on-prem PowerBI dashboard to on-prem SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, powerbi

We want to share PowerBI Report Server dashboard on sharepoint.
We add a page viewer (like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39550.create-power-bi-report-and-publish-in-sharepoint.aspx#Publish_the_report_to_SharePoint_On-Premise_environment)) or especialy iframe targeting (with [Embed](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/reportserver-quickstart-embed/) parameter) to report on PBI RS (itself this report works perfectly).
After that, report on sharepoint page appeared, but permanently showing "Loading Data...",
However, I catch successfull requests to our SSAS Cube in profiler, similar I see when report loaded natively from PBI RS.
Is there any another trick to Embed dashboard on SharePoint?

Comment: similar question was asked [here](https://www.kasperonbi.com/embedding-power-bi-reports-with-power-bi-report-server/#comment-3448467141), but there is no replyes on that...

Comment: moreover, [SSRS team blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/09/22/embed-paginated-reports-into-sharepoint-using-the-report-viewer-web-part/) reference [this](https://www.kasperonbi.com/embedding-power-bi-reports-with-power-bi-report-server/) article in context of embedding powerbi and mobile reports into sharepoint pages.
so, it must work, but it does not...